# Bootstrap 4 sticky-top not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to make the sidebar stick to the top. This works when the screen is smaller than the `sm` breakpoint, but larger than that, it doesn't stick. I thought the culprit could be the order of the class names, so I tried moving them but same results.

`sticky-top` works with `col-sm-*` but not with `col-*`. Why?

My code is in HAML and SCSS, I hope that's okay. [Refer to this pen](https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/vdybKN)

```
.container
  %ul.nav
    %li.nav-item
      %a.nav-link{:href => "#"}
        Menu
    %li.nav-item
      %a.nav-link{:href => "#"}
        Active
    %li.nav-item
      %a.nav-link{:href => "#"}
        Link
  .row
    .col-sm-3.sticky-top#sidebar
      This sidebar should stick to the top, both in expanded view and stacked view.
    .col-sm-9#main
      This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top.
      This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top.
      This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top.
      This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top.
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 120%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;

  .row {    
    > #sidebar {
      background:#ccc;
    }
    > #main {
      background: #eee;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#sidebar` is as tall as the content, so there is no space for the sidebar to fix... so add `.align-self-start` to your `#sidebar`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQbLPR

See also: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: thanks it worked! Does this mean that `sticky-top` will only stick until I get past the bottom border of the element that has that class?

Comment: (^answering my own question) yes that seems to be the case because I tried to duplicated the entire `row` and the sidebar stuck only until I reached the second row. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks. Worked like charm!